# How to supply a templatized item that is not present as a parameter (only in the function body) in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to write a templatized function in C++ where 4 total items are templatized (T, T2, T3, T4).  Two of these appear as parameters in the function (T3 and T4).  However, there are two other items that I want to templatize (T and T2) that are present only in the function body, not in the parameter list.

```
template <typename T, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4>
void foo (T3 edges, T4 distance)
{
 ...
 T xmin;
 T2 normal;
 ...
}
```

When I try to do this, I get compiler errors for "undefined reference to foo".  Any recommendations for how to templatize items that are only present in the function body, not the parameter list?

Note: foo is defined in a cpp file, and then I have specific instantiations also in the cpp file.

Comment: Where is `foo` defined? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/3309790) might help.

Comment: As a design note, it seems like the types `T` and `T2` ought to be related to `T3` and `T4`. Have you considered making them dependent types? E.g. Replace `T` with something like `T3::weight_type` or `edge_traits<T3>::weight_type` and define the required type alias/trait specialization for your edge class?

Comment: 90% chance this is your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: @songyuanyao, I added where foo is defined.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your **function template** `foo<>` inside a header as shown in the example below:

**mytemplates.h**

```
#ifndef MYTEMPLATE_H
#define MYTEMPLATE_H
template <typename T, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4>
void foo (T3 edges, T4 distance)
{
 
 T xmin;
 T2 normal;
 
 
}
#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "mytemplates.h"


int main() 
{
    std::string s = "name";
    foo<int, float>("string literal", s);
  
}
```

The output of the program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/XKaM_QAUI).

Comment: Thanks Anoop, but since I have the definition & specific instantiations in the cpp file, I don't think that this is my issue.

Comment: @nordstar You're welcome. Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we don't have to guess what files you have and what you're actually doing. We don't have anything to correct/modify in your current program.